# Row concurrency problems multi threading

Tags: sql, sql-server, concurrency

I am having troubles with concurrency. A 3rd party software is executing my Stored Procedure which I need to capture a unique list of IDs in a table. The code works until multi threading is brought into the mix (*gasp*).

I have tried various transaction features including isolation levels to seemingly no avail.

Essentially given the following, I need table 'IDList' to contain only the unique IDs that have ever been sent.

When other threads from the 3rd party software execute the example calling code, I consistently end up with duplicates in 'IDList'. It is my estimation that the following is happening, but am unable to resolve:

- Thread #1 runs the SELECT (with JOIN) in insertMissingIDs
- Thread #2 runs the SELECT (with JOIN) in insertMissingIDs
- Thread #1 runs the INSERT in insertMissingIDs
- Thread #2 runs the INSERT in insertMissingIDs

**Result: Duplicates**

I realize the example may seem silly, I have boiled it down as not to reveal confidential code.

**Calling code:**

```
DECLARE @ids IdType
INSERT INTO @ids
SELECT '123'

EXEC insertMissingIDs @ids
```

**User defined Type:**

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IdType] AS TABLE(
    [ID] [nvarchar](250) NULL
)
```

**Procedure:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertMissingIDs] 
    @ids IdType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO IDList (ID)
    SELECT p.ID
    FROM @ids i
    LEFT JOIN IDList ON i.ID = IDList.ID
    WHERE IDList.ID IS NULL
END
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like maybe you need some table locking?

Comment: Thanks @ControlAltDel, I've tried, hence: "I have tried various transaction features including isolation levels to seemingly no avail."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you basically have two choices.  You can set the appropriate transaction isolation level (documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)).  I think using `set transaction isolation level serializable` would do the trick.  This could introduce a *big* overhead on your transactions.  You would be locking the table for both reads and writes.  One call will have to wait for the previous one to finish. In more complicated situations, you might end up with a deadlock.

Another option is to define the primary key table `IDLIST` using the `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` option.  This allows inserts into the table.  If duplicates are in the data being inserted, they are ignored.

[Here](http://web.archive.org/web/20180404165346/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2013/02/01/a-creative-use-of-ignore-dup-key.aspx) is a blog post about creative ways to use this option.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should probably put a unique key on `IDList(ID)` in any event.  That will guarantee that there are no duplicates, though in the case of concurrent processes above, one of the process would get an error instead.

If you want to insure that both processes can execute concurrently without error, then change the stored procedure's isolation to serializable and add transaction-handling.

Something like this should work:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertMissingIDs] 
    @ids IdType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
    Begin Transaction

        INSERT INTO IDList (ID)
        SELECT p.ID
        FROM @ids i
        LEFT JOIN IDList ON i.ID = IDList.ID
        WHERE IDList.ID IS NULL
    Commit Transaction
END
```

Of course you might get some blocking also.

Comment: Thank you. I was lead to believe this as well, but I tried exactly that prior to posting this topic, no change.

Comment: This does work. If it does not work for you then either you are not really doing this (though it may appear similar), or your problem is not what you thought it was. In either case, applying the Unique Key I recommended above *guarantees* that it cannot happen, regardless if the code is correct or not.

Comment: It looks like the `left join ... where ... is null` does not result in a range lock, even at serializable.  [pastebin example](http://pastebin.com/Bi9FYtfN)

Comment: @Andomar then I'd say this is a bug in SQL Server.

Comment: @Andomar And adding a Unique Key does indeed fix it.

Comment: I re-implemented the transaction, and added the IGNORE_DUP_KEY as suggested by Gordon Linoff. A combination of these resolved the issue and is satisfactory for the needed purpose.